# Using "Ihr" as a formal singular "you"

Tags: pronoun, formality

I set the video game "Torchlight II" to the German language, and I noticed that the characters use "Ihr" as the singular second-person pronoun (for example, "Ihr habt eine neue Quest").

I read elsewhere that "Ihr" was used as the formal singular "you" a long time ago, but has since been replaced by "Sie". The game takes place in a somewhat medieval era, so would that explain why they use "Ihr"? Does other German media that take place in the distant past usually use "Ihr" as the formal second-person pronoun, to match the time period, or is there another reason for this?

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate but in case you are unable to see this, I'll link to the duplicate question for your benefit: [second person singular ihr](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/12402/6502)

Comment: Thank you! Surprising that I did not find that question when I searched for it.

Comment: @Jengerer... the Stack.exchange search function isn't particularly helpful, neither in results nor in design