# Why do I see 'Ihr' form instead of du/Sie?

Tags: personal-pronoun, formality, salutation

I'm pretty new to German, but something I've learned is that formal form of 'Du' is 'Sie'.
However, I sometimes see that 'Ihr' is also used in singular, but what's the difference ?

As example, there is the famous "Ihr seid gestorben" in the Dark Souls games. Why not "Du bist .." or "Sie Sind .." ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Ihr" as second person singular](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12402/ihr-as-second-person-singular)

Answer (score 4):

The formal address "Sie" (3rd person plural) is relatively new (well, since 18th or 19th century). In former times, the respectful address was "Ihr" (2nd person plural). Thus in a medieval context, like in co the honorary address usually is "Ihr" instead of "Sie".

See also here on [wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform#Anrede_in_der_2._Person_Plural_(Ihr))